# How to compare corresponding multiple files with each other in the same directory

Tags: shell-script, diff

Hi so I have a folder like `/mell/908` which contains files as follows:

```
cf-mell-pos-908-tcg-4619e.txt
cf-mell-pos-908-tcw-4619e.txt
cf-mell-pos-908-usc-4619e.txt
cf-mell-pos-908-wi_board-4619e.txt
copper_qnt
tcg_mell_upload_lx.txt
tcw_mell_upload_lx.txt
usc_mell_upload_lx.txt
wi_board_mell_upload_lx.txt
```

Is there a way I can use the `diff` command to compare the corresponding files

- `cf-mell-pos-908-tcg-4619e.txt` and `tcg_mell_upload_lx.txt`
- `cf-mell-pos-908-tcw-4619e.txt` and `tcw_mell_upload_lx.txt`

and so on with each other without having to `diff` manually each pair one by one? I am running a Linux system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this option, assuming the string that matches in every pair of files is always in the same position:

```bsh
# loop over the files that start with 'cf-'
for f in cf-*.txt; do
  # extract the unique "code", e.g 'tcg'
  code=$(echo "$f" | cut -d'-' -f5)

  # match the looped file with the one that starts with the "code"
  echo "diff" *"-${code}"* "${code}"*.txt

  # perform your commands, in this case I use an `echo` to show
  # how the command `diff` will be executed
done

diff cf-mell-pos-908-tcg-4619e.txt tcg_mell_upload_lx.txt
diff cf-mell-pos-908-tcw-4619e.txt tcw_mell_upload_lx.txt
diff cf-mell-pos-908-usc-4619e.txt usc_mell_upload_lx.txt
diff cf-mell-pos-908-wi_board-4619e.txt wi_board_mell_upload_lx.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful.